# How do I build this complex sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables

T1

```
ID | Name | IMAGE
------------------------
1    Peter  pic_111.jpg
2    Mark   pic222.jpg
```

T2

```
ID1 | ID2 | message | timestamp
```

If Peter sends Mark a message, Peter is ID1 and mark is ID2
and if Mark sends Peter a message Mark is ID1 and peter ID2,

I want to select image from T1 for ID1 and ID2

All messages from mark to someone or from someone to Mark
`select ID1,ID2, message from T2 where ID1=2 OR ID2=2` returns all message send from or to mark

How do I include picture for ID1 and ID2 to this query?

`select ID1, ID2, message, image from T1, T2 where ID1=2 OR ID2=2 T1.ID=ID1` will be wrong as I need image for UID1 AND uid2...

So it will be possible to show picture of person whos end mark a message or who mark sent a message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join `T1` twice in order to get the respective `ID` for each sender on `T2`.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.Image as ID1IMAGE, -- alias is needed to avoid ambiguous columns
        c.Image as ID2Image
FROM    T2 a
        INNER JOIN T1 b
            ON a.ID1 = b.ID
        INNER JOIN T1 c
            ON a.ID2 = c.ID
WHERE   2 IN (a.ID1, a.ID2)   -- the condition can be done like this.
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query in SQL like this

select image from T1 where id in (select ID1,ID2, message from T2 where ID1=2 OR ID2=2)

I am not sure to use in after where but you can try to use IN,ANY,ALL...